# Criar uma table temporária ou realizar um join de 4 tabelas umas com mais campos do que outras

Tags: mysql

Possuo cinco tabelas, *cis* com os campos `id`, `id_referencia`, `tipoci` e `numci`, as outras são `cigeral`, `ciintercambio`, `cihoraextra` e `cicompensacao`.

Quando crio uma das *cis* dou um `insert` na tabela referente ao tipo de `ci` e
um `insert` na tabela `cis` referenciando o `id` da `ci` criada no campo `id_referencia` e no campo `tipoci` indico o tipo e a lógica cria o número da `ci` no campo `numci`, pois apesar de serem de tipos diferentes todas devem seguir a mesma ordem de numeração.

O problema é que não consigo criar uma  query que busque todas as cis de todas as tabelas porque as tabelas possuem alguns campos iguais porém umas têm mais campos que outras, por exemplo:

`cigeral` possui os campos: `id`, `tipoci`, `id_user`, `destino`, `assunto`, `dataci` e `discriminacao`.

`ciintercambio` possui os campos: `id`, `tipoci`, `id_user`, `destino`, `assunto`, `dataci`, `intercambista`, `dataintercambio` e `turno`

Queria uma *query* que me retornasse todos os campos das 4 tabelas baseado no `id_referÊncia` da tabela `cis`. os campos que não existissem nas demais tabelas fossem mostrados como `null`.

Quando realizo a query abaixo ele me retorna somente as 3 `cis` de intercambio com seus respectivos números de cis, as outras 8, que são de tipos diferentes aparecem com todos os dados como `null`.

```
SELECT cis.numci, ciintercambio.* from cis LEFT JOIN ciintercambio on cis.id_referencia = ciintercambio.id AND cis.tipoci = 2
```

Comment: Olá! Ajudaria se desse um pequeno exemplo das tabelas, conteúdo delas e resultado esperado no `SELECT`.

Comment: Descreva aí que `cis.tipoci` corresponde a que tabela (`ciintercambio`, `cigeral`, `cihoraextra` e `cicompensacao`). Isto está me cheirando a mais um caso de UNION com LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim (não é nem LEFT JOIN, é (INNER) JOIN):

```
SELECT cis.tipoci, i.id, cis.numci, i.id_user, i.destino, i.assunto, i.dataci,
       i.intercambista, i.dataintercambio, i.turno, NULL AS discriminacao
FROM cis
JOIN ciintercambio i ON i.id = cis.id_referencia AND cis.tipoci IN (2)

UNION

SELECT cis.tipoci, g.id, cis.numci, g.id_user, g.destino, g.assunto, g.dataci,
       NULL, NULL, NULL, g.discriminacao
FROM cis
JOIN cigeral g ON g.id = cis.id_referencia AND cis.tipoci IN (<TIPOS_DO_CIGERAL>)

UNION

...
```

Preencha as reticências acima com as demais consultas equivalentes - para o caso de cada tabela faltante, `cihoraextra` e `cicompensacao` -, sempre cuidando para que as **colunas** que **não** existam na tabela estejam devidamente com seus NULLs.

E nomeie as colunas no primeiro SELECT da consulta.

Comment: O caminho foi esse. Consegui resolver. Vou colocar abaixo a consulta completa que criou a minha view.

Answer (score 1):

Assim resolvi meu problema. Se alguém tiver alguma melhoria a fazer na consulta, aceito conselhos. obrigado pessoal.

```
CREATE view todas_as_cis AS
 SELECT cis.numci, u.nome, cis.id, i.tipoci, i.id_user, i.destino, 
 i.assunto, i.dataci, null as datacompensacao, null as discriminacao, 
 i.intercambista, i.dataintercambio,i.turno, null as turnoinicio, null 
 as turnofim, null as dataextra, null as credito, null as posto, null 
 as extrainicio, null as extrafim, null as agentes FROM `cis` left 
 join ciintercambio i on cis.id_referencia = i.id LEFT JOIN usuario u 
 ON i.id_user = u.id_user WHERE cis.tipoci = 2 
 UNION 
 SELECT cis.numci, u.nome, cis.id, g.tipoci, g.id_user, g.destino, 
 g.assunto, g.dataci, null as datacompensacao, g.discriminacao, null 
 as intercambista, null as dataintercambio, null as turno, null as 
 turnoinicio, null as turnofim, null as dataextra, null as credito, 
 null as posto, null as extrainicio, null as extrafim, null as agentes 
 FROM `cis` left join cigeral g on cis.id_referencia = g.id LEFT JOIN 
 usuario u ON g.id_user = u.id_user WHERE cis.tipoci = 1
 UNION
 SELECT cis.numci, u.nome, cis.id, c.tipoci, c.id_user, c.destino, 
 c.assunto, c.dataci, c.datacompensacao, null as discriminacao, null 
 as intercambista, null as dataintercambio, null as turno, null as 
 turnoinicio, null as turnofim, null as dataextra, null as credito, 
 null as posto, null as extrainicio, null as extrafim, null as agentes 
 FROM `cis` left join cicompensacao c on cis.id_referencia = c.id LEFT 
 JOIN usuario u ON c.id_user = u.id_user WHERE cis.tipoci = 4
 UNION
 SELECT cis.numci, u.nome, cis.id, h.tipoci, h.id_user, h.destino, 
 h.assunto, h.dataci, null as datacompensacao, null as discriminacao, 
 null as intercambista, null as dataintercambio, null as turno, 
 h.turnoinicio, h.turnofim, h.dataextra, h.credito, h.posto, 
 h.extrainicio, h.extrafim, h.agentes FROM `cis` left join cihoraextra 
 h on cis.id_referencia = h.id LEFT JOIN usuario u ON h.id_user = 
 u.id_user WHERE cis.tipoci = 3
```